# Reference for hierarchical Bayesian modelling

Tags: references, hierarchical-bayesian

I am currently reading "Bayesian Data Analysis" by Gelman et al. and my main goal was to learn about Hierarchical modelling on chapter 5. I read until chapter 4 and the book is written terribly for a taste of a math student as it is pretty sketchy and engineering oriented.

I decided to not to continue anymore with this book and I would be very grateful if somebody could introduce a reference with a more rigorous approach to the topic.

Comment: Maybe I should move the question to math exchange, any suggestions?

Comment: I totally agree with your opinion about Gelman et al's book. Try *The Bayesian choice*, by C. Robert.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent pretty happy that got the same opinion from somebody else. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a [new edition of Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Analysis-Edition-Chapman-Statistical/dp/1439840954) coming out soon.  I don't know if it would be better for your taste, but it looks like it will have a lot of other improvements.

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris This book will always be nubearable for me. Too much text, not enough mathematics. There's more information in one half page of *The Bayesian Choice* than in 5 pages of Gelman et al's book. This book provides some cooking recipes for Bayesian analysis: some recommendations without any theoretical justification. I've also started to read [Gelman & Hill's book](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/). Nice to learn R & WinBUGS, but the practical approach is grisly, for example the authors fit Gaussian models to data far, far , far to be Gaussian,  without worrying about that.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/Papers/devsci07_kempetal.pdf) is a really good 15-page article by Kemp at al. on Hierarchical Bayesian Modelling. It is more conceptual than mathematical though so I don't know whether it is good for your taste. Having said that, it definitely is less of a commitment than reading an entire book.

Comment: Hehe, thank you but this is actually the article I was reading that brought me into the field and I started looking for a more mathematically detailed source for it...